# Is local multiplayer (local network, multiple consoles) possible on Doom on Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch, doom-2016

I've established that:

- There is no support for local *split screen* multiplayer for Doom on Nintendo Switch, and probably never will be. Apparently the days of splitscreen FPS similar to Goldeneye on the N64 are over, sadly.
- When Doom was first released for Nintendo Switch, there was no *online* multiplayer, but a very large patch after release fixed this and online multiplayer is now a possibility, if you download the very large update.

However between all the hundreds of articles on the above two controversies, I can't find out:

1. Can two or more people, with two or more Switch consoles, in the same room, start a private multiplayer Doom game, for just them, without needing to go online?
2. If yes:

   1. Does this require an extra copy of the Doom game per player? (multiple cartridges or downloads)
   2. Does this require any/all players to have an account with or subscription to the Nintendo online gaming service?

Answer (score 1):

As of date, it's not possible to have multiplayer session just for local party.

However, it has party option which allows to play online multiplayer with your friends (as like you, your friends and bunch of other folks on the same server). You can see party option in bottom right corner:
[image: multiplayer libby]

As for accounts, on [Nintendo game store's Doom page](https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/doom-switch) it is listed that:

> Nintendo Account required. Online features will be free until the Nintendo Switch Online Service launches in 2018

So I think all players need copy of game and Online Service subscription.